# accuracy drop between tensorflow model and converted tflite

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I'm running into an issue where I convert my keras model into tensorflow lite format but once I do the model accuracy of the converted model drops significantly. The model is a fairly simple natural language processing model. Before conversion the model has an accuracy of around 96%, but once it is converted into the tensorflow lite format (without any optimizations) it drops to around 20%. This is a ridiculous drop in performance so I was wondering is this something that can happen or am I doing something wrong here? I am running the tflite model on a beaglebone SBC running debian and running the inferences on python.

My tflite conversion code:

```
 converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
 tflite_model = converter.convert()

 with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(tflite_model)
```

My model code:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 128, input_length=maxlen),
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(24, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
```

Comment: That accuracy drop cannot be caused by conversion itself. I would check firstly if trained model goes as input to convertor. Also such behavior can be caused by missed preprocess if you have any during training.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. I solved it with post-training quantization. So I applied quantization on my trained model, and retrain it. It reduced the accuracy significantly that there was no more than roughly 2-10% difference on keras and TFLite.

It seems that when a keras model was converted to TFLite, a sort of quantization was also applied and the float parameters were converted to integers, which resulted in the accuracy drop. By quantizing the model first, we trained the model with integers. I think this is more or less what happened. Correct me if I'm wrong

References
https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/quantization/training
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/model_optimization